# How to send a request to another server in a django view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, httprequest

I want to send an `http` request to another server in my `django view` like this:

```
def django_view(request):
    response = send_request('http://example.com')
    result = do_something_with_response(response)
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You're probably searching for the wrong thing. The "j" in "ajax" stands for JavaScript, if you want to make an async request in Python to modify your view, you'd have to implement some sort of web socket thing to update the browser when the request completed anyways. For something like this, you probably just have to write it in JS as a jQuery ajax request or something

Comment: @pdom: yeah, I actually nead an HttpRequest. thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`python requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to send the request and get the response. But you will need to format the response for your need.

Here is an example of `GET` request:

```
import requests

def django_view(request):
    # get the response from the URL
    response = requests.get('http://example.com')
    result = do_something_with_response(response)
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

The only caveat is that if you do it here it won't be `ajax` (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) anymore. The alternative would be that you load your webpage from django view normally and then perform all the AJAX requests in javascript -  further processing the response and rendering it in the page.