# Django localhost refusing connection from another django localhost

Tags: django, python-requests

I have two django applications, currently running on localhost. I plan to have them on two separate servers, but for now, they are running on my machine.

App `A` is running on `:8000`

App `B` is running on `:8010`

When I try to make a request from `A` to `B` by using:

```
import requests

requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:8010/api/plan', data=post_data)
```

I get a connection error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8010): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/plan (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f82fed36630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

In my `B` app I have `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Anyone has any idea what am I missing?

Comment: i don't know about request . but you may consider using django-cors-headers

Comment: check this answer this will help you to solve your problem
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324889/how-to-send-a-request-to-another-server-in-a-django-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324889/how-to-send-a-request-to-another-server-in-a-django-view)

Comment: @Ankit I'm using python-requests already

Answer (score 0):

You should add [cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) to your projects settings.py

For example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "corsheaders",
    # ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    # ...
]
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_METHODS = [
    "GET", "POST" # add allowed methods here
]

CORS_URLS_REGEX = r"^/api/.*$"

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change anything for me. Postman calls work correctly, but I still get connection error on django request.